# Rails: Maximum image file upload size using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I'm setting up a feature in a rails application for users to upload image files and I'm using the paperclip gem (v ~> 5.0.0). It appears I cannot upload images greater than 2MB. I see that there are validations for the file sizes and understand how that works, but I have yet to find solid documentation of the maximum size anywhere. The largest image upload I am anticipating for this site is 36MB.

If other gems exist that would be useful, feel free to suggest. Thanks

Comment: The size is validated in the model. Can you post the model you added the gem to?

Comment: Are you using nginx to server the app in production by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in the model you added paperclip to should do it:

```
validates_attachment :image, presence: true, size: { less_than: 40.megabytes }
```

Make sure there isn't this line already there set to something lower

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip introduces several validators to validate your attachment

You can try one of this

```
validates :avatar, attachment_presence: true
validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, attributes: :avatar
validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, attributes: :avatar, less_than: 10.megabytes
```

Lastly, you can also define multiple validations on a single attachment using validates_attachment:

```
validates_attachment :avatar, presence: true,
content_type: { content_type: "image/jpeg" },
size: { in: 0..10.megabytes }
```

This works for me.